# DNS entry always preferring wildcard entry instead of explicit entry

Tags: domain-name-system, routeros

I have a Mikrotik Router with Router OS where I need to set a static DNS entry. I have set

- a url `exhibitorsearch.test.intern.customer.com` to an ip with the ending .92
- a regexp `.*\.test\.intern\.customer\.com` to an ip with the ending .91

[image]

The explicit url comes before the regexp url. The problem is that when I run `dig exhibitorsearch.test.intern.customer.com` I always get an answer with .91. I've tried switching them around so maybe the last entry wins, but to no avail. I have also waited five minutes because of the TTL to expire and renew the entry.

How can I get for the explicit url the .92 and how can I get the .91 for everything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Citing the [documentation](https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:IP/DNS#Static_DNS_Entries):

> The list is ordered and is checked from top to bottom. Regular expressions are checked first, then the plain records.

I would try the following workarounds

- Try to use non-regex wildcards. These are a standard DNS feature (unlike the regex-variant) and in that case, the more specific records should have precedence.

  ```
  *.test.intern.example.com
  exhibitorsearch.test.intern.example.com
  ```
- Try to build a regexp that excludes `exhibitorsearch`.

Comment: Thanks for finding that in the documentation. First suggestion did not work. When using `*.test.intern.example.com` as DNS entry, I can `dig *.test.intern.example.com`, but for `dig asdf.test.intern.example.com` I don't get an answer. We ended up setting both entries as a regex, with the more specifc entry before the * entry.